# Windows Forms Page MultiLocalization

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, globalization

I'm listing the things I want to do to my project in the github account below, but what I can't. I would be glad if you help.

- The language selected during the runtime is valid again when the program is opened and closed.
- Resx of a string expression in the code. identification by pulling from the file.
- All of the above operations must be such that they affect all forms.

You can also clone and test the project or suggest me a source or solution.

Thank you

Comment: [Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-and-localization).

Comment: I said for winforms. This resource adequately met my needs